# How to run a script with a for loop by sudo command

Tags: bash, for-loop, sudo

I was making a script, when I found a problem with sudo command and for loop.

I have this test script

```
for i in {0..10..2}
do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

Normal output should be this:

```
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

But it shows this:`Welcome {0..10..2} times`
any ideas ?

bash version:4.3.11(1)-release

Comment: try `for i in $(seq 0 2 10)`

Comment: Hw are you running the script, guessing you are using sh. Use bash.

Comment: No, it showed me this: Welcome 0 times  with or without sudo
,I am using bash

Comment: In your bash version, it works fine. You might be doing something wrong while executing the script.

Comment: well, I am executing it through the console

Comment: are you doing `bash filename` while executing or if `./filename` have you written `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: i doubt your shell in super user is not bash or it's bash but in posix mode. so it doesn't do the expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell in `sudo` does not do brace expansion.

```
$ cat s.sh 
echo $SHELL
echo $SHELLOPTS
for i in {0..10..2}
      do
        echo "Welcome $i times"
      done

$ ./s.sh
/bin/bash
braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times

$ sudo ./s.sh
/bin/bash

Welcome {0..10..2} times
```

Use `seq()` as others have suggested.

Comment: And you  can change this with `set -B` or `set +B`

Answer (score 1):

The `{0..10..2}` syntax is only supported in Bash 4.

For Bash 3, use this syntax instead:

```
$ for ((i=0; i<=10; i+=2)); do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

You can see what is happening in Bash 3.2 if you remove the step part of the brace expansion:

```
bash-3.2$ for i in {0..10..2}; do echo "i=>$i"; done
i=>{0..10..2}
bash-3.2$ for i in {0..10}; do echo "i=>$i"; done
i=>0
i=>1
i=>2
i=>3
i=>4
i=>5
i=>6
i=>7
i=>8
i=>9
i=>10
```

BUT on Bash 4, it works as you desired it to:

```
bash-4.3$ for i in {0..10..2}; do echo "i=>$i"; done
i=>0
i=>2
i=>4
i=>6
i=>8
i=>10
```

---

**Edit**

As Nathan Wilson correctly points out, this is probably the result of the Bash option `braceexpand` being negative.

You can set this value with [set](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

```
$ echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:posix
$ for i in {0..5}; do echo "i=>$i"; done
i=>0
i=>1
i=>2
i=>3
i=>4
i=>5
$ set +B
$ echo $SHELLOPTS
emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:posix
$ for i in {0..5}; do echo "i=>$i"; done
i=>{0..5}
```

Comment: I have 4.3.11(1)-release

Comment: It is being executed by Bash 3 without you being aware of that. Try inserting `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood you correctly, but you can use below code to generate the same output. Here's my test script

```
for i in $(seq 0 5)
  do
     echo "Welcome $(( $i * 2)) times"
 done
```

> Output

```
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

More detail on `seq` command can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seq_%28Unix%29)

Comment: Also, please do remember to accept your answers (all of them) if they have given you satisfactory answers (by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answers), it would be helpful to the community

Comment: But this does not answer the question of why `Welcome {0..10..2} times` is getting output. The answer you wrote can also be written as `for i in $(seq 0 2 10); do echo "Welcome $i times"; done` as mentioned in comments by @ReutSharabani

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the script should be this:

`for i in $(seq 0 5)
  do
     echo "Welcome $(( $i * 2)) times"
 done` thank you [my-thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1781222/my-thoughts).

Comment: You can use `$(seq 0 2 10)` as mentioned in comment by @ReutSharabani, and in for loop `echo "Welcome $i times"`

Comment: yes, but that doesn't work. At least not for me as i already mentioned